# Connect exception when discovering active mq queues using hermes JMS

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have created an active mq session in hermes jms. However when I try to discover queues on the broker I get a Connect exception:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In session properties you should have specified a `serviceUrl` like:

```
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
```

[image]

This specifies the url to JMX connector for active mq. Active Mq must be running a JXM connector at this port for Hermes Jms to connect to it.

Check that port is open:

```
netstat -lntp | grep 1099
```

Or check the Active MQ startup log. It must show a line like:

```
INFO | JMX consoles can connect to service:jmx:rmi://localhost:1593/jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
```

If there is no JMX connector on that port, edit `activemq.xml` in `conf` directory of active mq installation.

Change `createConnector` to `true`:

```
<managementContext>
   <managementContext createConnector="true"/>
 </managementContext>
```

Restart active mq.